# Dashboard in SharePoint for SQL Server Jobs

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have multiple SQL jobs running on daily basis to integrate different systems and build a DW.  I don't have time to support them and I want to hand over the support to a support team that have minimum knowledge of SQL Server.  How to do that?

I was thinking of having a dashboard published on Sharepoint where the support team can see if all the jobs have run successfully and if not, start the jobs from sharepoint.  Is this the right approach? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to develop a web part using the code [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/367470/Manage-SQL-Server-Agent-Jobs-using-Csharp) to display and add control to SQL Agent Jobs.  It's a good way to limit what they can see and do, though it'd take some time to create.